# Accessing error messages for nested attribute field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, haml, simple-form

I have a form created using the simple_form gem which populates 2 models using nested attributes. I want to check if there are any errors and display a new block. However, I'm not sure how to correctly access the error message for the `location` attribute of the `Booking` model.

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  attr_accessible :date_wanted, :location
end
```

and

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings

  attr_accessible :name, :phone, :bookings_attributes

  validates_presence_of :name, :phone
end
```

Form view:

```
simple_form_for @customer, {:html => { :class => "form-horizontal" }} do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :phone
  = f.simple_fields_for :bookings do |b|
    = b.input :date
    = b.input :location
    - if @customer.errors[:appointments_attributes][:location]
      # insert code if any validation errors for the date field were found
  = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`b` is an instance of form builder, holding `booking`, so you can try:

```
# ...
if b.object.errors[:location]
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm able to see if there are any error messages by using if `b.object.errors[:location].empty?`.